# how to display profile in a already opened tab in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a web application in the flask. My main page displays the list of author names. When I click on the name, a new tab opens to display the author's profile information. If I click on another name from the main page, another tab gets opened.
I want a solution to open only one tab if I click on the author's name one by one e.g previously opened tab should get closed before opening new tab.
Is it possible?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The web browser itself is responsible for opening / disposing of tabs when you click on links, and the idea of a "tab" doesn't necessarily even need to exist, some browsers don't have such a thing. For example, the mobile browser Firefox Focus can only have one page open at a time.

> previously opened tab should get closed before opening new tab. Is it possible?

To put it simply, no. There is such a thing as javascript's [Window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close), but this can only apply to the page that the code was executed in, you have no control over other tabs that a user may or may not have open on their local machine.  If you consider the example of Google Chrome, the basis of the "tab" construct is that tabs are isolated objects, in fact they each get their own OS process and don't directly communicate.

So what can you do to address your problem?  Here are a few ideas

- When an author is clicked in the list, use javascript to insert a new element containing their profile information without loading a new page.  You could add the javascript tag to your queston to try and get some help in that area
- When an author is clicked in the list, use flask's templating to reload the same page but with the selected author's profile template embedded in the page. https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#include

In either case, this question seems to be escaping the domain of Python, consider re-tagging or opening a new question with more focus